# 'ObjectId' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have searched but couldn't find a proper answer. I am new to stackoverflow and typescript. I am getting an error while creating a Mongoose Schema, my code looks like this:

```js
import  { Schema, ObjectId } from 'mongoose'

interface IArticle {
    title: string
    userId: ObjectId
    thumb: string
    slug: string
    children: object[]
    claps: number
}

const articleSchema = new Schema<IArticle>({
    -------
    userId: {
        type: ObjectId, // ERROR HERE!!!
        required: true
    },
    -------
})
```

But it gives error that `'ObjectId' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

tsconfig.json has the following content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        "incremental": true,

        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "./src" ,                       
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

I have also used `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of `ObjectId`, but then get the following error:

`Type 'typeof ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof SchemaType': cast, checkRequired, set, getts(2322)`

mongoose   => 6.0.5
typescript => 4.4.3

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dunno why you're getting that error, because it works fine for me. What is your `Typescript` and `mongoose` version? And you could try using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of `mongoose.ObjectId`

Comment: @Kapobajza I have updated the question, also tried using `ObjectId` from `bson` and `mongodb` but get similar errors

Comment: @Kapobajza solved it, thanks. Added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tried Using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead of `mongoose.ObjectId`. and it worked.

my **not-so-clear** understanding of why it gave an error:

`mongoose.ObjectId` is an alias for `type ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` which can only be used as a type, not as a "value" for type property in mongoose schema.

`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` refers to the actual class, hence can be used both as a type and value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I just put this export at the top of a file I export type checking functions from.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export type TObjectId = mongoose.ObjectId;
export const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```